# Seemingly inexplicable result of CGAffineTransformInvert

Tags: ios, cgaffinetransform

Folks,  [Edited at end to add new information]

I am either at my wit's end or completely lacking in wits, not sure which, so any help would be loverly…

I have two views in a container view. The state of each subview is defined, in part, by a CGAffineTransform. Call each 'initial' transform 'M', then at some time, after an arbitrary series of gestures, the 'final' state is defined by transform 'N'. The task is to extract the cumulative effect of the gestures in a transform 'Q' such that:

Q: QM -> N

so I thought

QM(M_Inverse) -> N(M_Inverse)

i.e.
Q = N(M_Inverse), problem solved [NOT].

Tested the simple code below (now peppered with nslogs) with the simplest case (a translation in X-Y applied equally to both subviews (not that they should matter because everything here is about transforms, but anyways).

```
- (void) saveLastTransform:(BOOL)returnA {
if (returnA) {
    helper.xformLastA  = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    if (svDelegate.isAlignmentActivated) {
        if ((int)(100.0 * helper.xformDefaultA.a) != 0) {
            NSLog(@"AM = %f, %f, %f", helper.xformDefaultA.a, helper.xformDefaultA.b, helper.xformDefaultA.tx);
            NSLog(@"     %f, %f, %f", helper.xformDefaultA.c, helper.xformDefaultA.d, helper.xformDefaultA.ty);
            CGAffineTransform defInvA = CGAffineTransformInvert(helper.xformDefaultA);
            NSLog(@"AM_1 = %f, %f, %f", defInvA.a, defInvA.b, defInvA.tx);
            NSLog(@"       %f, %f, %f", defInvA.c, defInvA.d, defInvA.ty);
            CGAffineTransform defInvAInv = CGAffineTransformInvert(defInvA);
            NSLog(@"AM_1_1 = %f, %f, %f", defInvAInv.a, defInvAInv.b, defInvAInv.tx);
            NSLog(@"         %f, %f, %f", defInvAInv.c, defInvAInv.d, defInvAInv.ty);
            CGAffineTransform ident = CGAffineTransformConcat(defInvA, helper.xformDefaultA);
            NSLog(@"Identity? = %f, %f, %f", ident.a, ident.b, ident.tx);
            NSLog(@"            %f, %f, %f", ident.c, ident.d, ident.ty);
            ident = CGAffineTransformConcat(defInvA, defInvAInv);
            NSLog(@"Identity? = %f, %f, %f", ident.a, ident.b, ident.tx);
            NSLog(@"            %f, %f, %f", ident.c, ident.d, ident.ty);
            ident = CGAffineTransformConcat(defInvAInv, defInvA);
            NSLog(@"Identity? = %f, %f, %f", ident.a, ident.b, ident.tx);
            NSLog(@"            %f, %f, %f", ident.c, ident.d, ident.ty);
            helper.xformLastA  = CGAffineTransformConcat([self getActiveTransform:groupA], defInvA);
            CGAffineTransform N = [self getActiveTransform:groupA];
            NSLog(@"AN = %f, %f, %f", N.a, N.b, N.tx);
            NSLog(@"     %f, %f, %f", N.c, N.d, N.ty);
            NSLog(@"AQ = %f, %f, %f", helper.xformLastA.a, helper.xformLastA.b, helper.xformLastA.tx);
            NSLog(@"     %f, %f, %f", helper.xformLastA.c, helper.xformLastA.d, helper.xformLastA.ty);
        }
    }
}
else {
    helper.xformLastB  = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    if (svDelegate.isAlignmentActivated) {
        if ((int)(100.0 * helper.xformDefaultB.a) != 0) {
            NSLog(@"BM = %f, %f, %f", helper.xformDefaultB.a, helper.xformDefaultB.b, helper.xformDefaultB.tx);
            NSLog(@"     %f, %f, %f", helper.xformDefaultB.c, helper.xformDefaultB.d, helper.xformDefaultB.ty);
            CGAffineTransform defInvB = CGAffineTransformInvert(helper.xformDefaultB);
            NSLog(@"BM_1 = %f, %f, %f", defInvB.a, defInvB.b, defInvB.tx);
            NSLog(@"       %f, %f, %f", defInvB.c, defInvB.d, defInvB.ty);
            CGAffineTransform defInvBInv = CGAffineTransformInvert(defInvB);
            NSLog(@"BM_1_1 = %f, %f, %f", defInvBInv.a, defInvBInv.b, defInvBInv.tx);
            NSLog(@"         %f, %f, %f", defInvBInv.c, defInvBInv.d, defInvBInv.ty);
            CGAffineTransform ident = CGAffineTransformConcat(defInvB, helper.xformDefaultB);
            NSLog(@"Identity? = %f, %f, %f", ident.a, ident.b, ident.tx);
            NSLog(@"            %f, %f, %f", ident.c, ident.d, ident.ty);
            ident = CGAffineTransformConcat(defInvB, defInvBInv);
            NSLog(@"Identity? = %f, %f, %f", ident.a, ident.b, ident.tx);
            NSLog(@"            %f, %f, %f", ident.c, ident.d, ident.ty);
            ident = CGAffineTransformConcat(defInvBInv, defInvB);
            NSLog(@"Identity? = %f, %f, %f", ident.a, ident.b, ident.tx);
            NSLog(@"            %f, %f, %f", ident.c, ident.d, ident.ty);
            helper.xformLastB  = CGAffineTransformConcat([self getActiveTransform:groupB], defInvB);
            CGAffineTransform N = [self getActiveTransform:groupB];
            NSLog(@"BN = %f, %f, %f", N.a, N.b, N.tx);
            NSLog(@"     %f, %f, %f", N.c, N.d, N.ty);
            NSLog(@"BQ = %f, %f, %f", helper.xformLastB.a, helper.xformLastB.b, helper.xformLastB.tx);
            NSLog(@"     %f, %f, %f", helper.xformLastB.c, helper.xformLastB.d, helper.xformLastB.ty);
        }
    }
}
```

}

If you look at the source matrices (AM & BM), you can 'see' the translation is the same for each set (AN & BN) but the inverse calculation for the second case is bizarre… either by hand or using the handy website: http://www.bluebit.gr/matrix-calculator/ I cannot see how that is a valid inverse (and the calculated Q reflects that fact).

```
Output
```

Transform 'A'

2013-05-17 13:19:18.349 AffineTest[16929:707] AM = 0.993584, -0.003874, 54.730000
2013-05-17 13:19:18.351 AffineTest[16929:707]      0.005911, 0.993446, 26.889999
2013-05-17 13:19:18.355 AffineTest[16929:707] AM_1 = 1.006434, 0.003925, -54.921101
2013-05-17 13:19:18.359 AffineTest[16929:707]        -0.005988, 1.006574, -27.281588
2013-05-17 13:19:18.371 AffineTest[16929:707] AM_1_1 = 0.993584, -0.003874, 54.730003
2013-05-17 13:19:18.375 AffineTest[16929:707]          0.005911, 0.993446, 26.889999
2013-05-17 13:19:18.379 AffineTest[16929:707] Identity? = 1.000000, 0.000000, -0.000002
2013-05-17 13:19:18.383 AffineTest[16929:707]             0.000000, 1.000000, -0.000001
2013-05-17 13:19:18.386 AffineTest[16929:707] Identity? = 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000002
2013-05-17 13:19:18.390 AffineTest[16929:707]             0.000000, 1.000000, -0.000001
2013-05-17 13:19:18.393 AffineTest[16929:707] Identity? = 1.000000, -0.000000, 0.000001
2013-05-17 13:19:18.397 AffineTest[16929:707]             -0.000000, 1.000000, -0.000000
2013-05-17 13:19:18.401 AffineTest[16929:707] AN = 0.993584, -0.003874, 308.729980
2013-05-17 13:19:18.405 AffineTest[16929:707]      0.005911, 0.993446, 220.889999
2013-05-17 13:19:18.408 AffineTest[16929:707] AQ = 1.000000, -0.000000, 254.472458
2013-05-17 13:19:18.411 AffineTest[16929:707]      -0.000000, 1.000000, 196.272278

Transform 'B'

2013-05-17 13:19:18.415 AffineTest[16929:707] BM = 0.753817, 0.038102, 344.529999
2013-05-17 13:19:18.419 AffineTest[16929:707]      -0.041526, 0.740303, 152.130005
2013-05-17 13:19:18.422 AffineTest[16929:707] BM_1 = 1.322831, -0.068084, -467.043274
2013-05-17 13:19:18.425 AffineTest[16929:707]        0.074201, 1.346979, -181.458923
2013-05-17 13:19:18.429 AffineTest[16929:707] BM_1_1 = 0.753817, 0.038102, 344.530029
2013-05-17 13:19:18.432 AffineTest[16929:707]          -0.041526, 0.740303, 152.130005
2013-05-17 13:19:18.435 AffineTest[16929:707] Identity? = 1.000000, -0.000000, -0.000008
2013-05-17 13:19:18.439 AffineTest[16929:707]             -0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000003
2013-05-17 13:19:18.442 AffineTest[16929:707] Identity? = 1.000000, -0.000000, -0.000005
2013-05-17 13:19:18.446 AffineTest[16929:707]             0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000003
2013-05-17 13:19:18.449 AffineTest[16929:707] Identity? = 1.000000, -0.000000, 0.000012
2013-05-17 13:19:18.452 AffineTest[16929:707]             0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000007
2013-05-17 13:19:18.456 AffineTest[16929:707] BN = 0.753817, 0.038102, 598.530029
2013-05-17 13:19:18.459 AffineTest[16929:707]      -0.041526, 0.740303, 346.130005
2013-05-17 13:19:18.463 AffineTest[16929:707] BQ = 1.000000, 0.000000, 350.394165
2013-05-17 13:19:18.466 AffineTest[16929:707]      0.000000, 1.000000, 244.020630

Yet multiple inversions restore the original transform and iOS says they are true inverses. Can someone please tell me what [blinding flash of the obvious] I'm missing here? Thanks!

Edit.

Turns out some of this is due to iOS convention that x' = xT instead of Tx so that the matrix is

|a  b  0|
|c  d  0|
|tx ty 1|

instead of the usual convention

|a  b tx|
|c  d ty|
|0  0  1|

so conventional matrix algebra seems to not apply. If I follow the chain down for the second case (using an external tool) I get:

M matrix:
  0.754   0.038 344.530
 -0.042   0.740 152.130
  0.000   0.000   1.000

M Inverse:
   1.322   -0.068 -445.302
   0.075    1.347 -230.855
   0.000    0.000    1.000

N Matrix
  0.754   0.038 598.530
 -0.042   0.740 346.130
  0.000   0.000   1.000

Q Matrix  = N x M-Inverse [CORRECT TRANSLATION]
  0.999   0.000 254.058
  0.001   1.000 193.719
  0.000   0.000   1.000

But using iOS form you get:

M matrix:
  0.754   0.038   0.000
 -0.042   0.740   0.000
344.530 152.130   1.000

M Inverse:
   1.323   -0.068    0.000
   0.074    1.347    0.000
-467.043 -181.459    1.000

N Matrix:
  0.754   0.038   0.000
 -0.042   0.740   0.000
598.530 346.130   1.000

Q Matrix = N x M-Inverse [WRONG TRANSLATION]
  1.000   0.000   0.000
  0.000   1.000   0.000
350.426 244.078   1.000

But Q' = M-Inverse x N [CORRECT??? TRANSLATION]
  1.000   0.000   0.000
 -0.001   1.000   0.000
254.001 194.103   1.000

This just seems so wrong - what on earth is going on here. Is there an alternate universe in which this makes [mathematical] sense???

Comment: Really, what is your problem? floating point inaccuracy? I'm looking through your code and the logs but I can't understand what your problem is? Are you feeling that `CGAffineTransformInvert( )` is giving you a incorrect result or is it multiplying the matrices with `CGAffineTransformConcat( )` that is the problem?

Comment: From what I can see in your logs `inv(inv(A)) == A` as it should be and `inv(A)*A == I` and `A*inv(A) == I` as it should be. The same is true for B

Comment: 2 problems: [1] If I hand-multiply (okay calculator-multiply) BM and BM-Inverse I should get identity - I don't [2] if my logic is correct AQ should =BQ since the translation is the same but AQ is 'correct' and BQ is not.

Comment: Editing body of question based on new discovery